# Downloaded car design does not appear in car selection or my designs menu

Tags: forza-horizon-2, forza-motorsport-5, forza-motorsport-6

I had some cars in Forza 5, Forza Horizon 2 and recently in Forza 6 where I downloaded a design for a car but it would not be permanent.

In Horizon 2 I remember selecting a design that would apply on the car but not to the thumbnail. I could drive races and championships with the design but when I switch for another car and back the design would be gone.

In Forza 5 I remember that I downloaded designs for several cars successfully, leaving the game and shutting down the console, on next launch some designs were missing. I tried it several times with one car, it was reproducible.

In Forza 6 it's a bit different (to Horizon, since there is no open world mode) and the design will not apply to the car at all.

In all of these cases I can find designs for all the other cars in the *my designs* menu, but not for these cars.

- Is there a solution?
- Which cars are affected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Which cars are affected:** In almost all cases these cars already have designs applied to them.

**Solution:** I found this tip in the [forums](http://forums.forzamotorsport.net/turn10_postsm249509_Saving-design-does-not-always-save-the-design.aspx#post_249509), go to the menu where you can paint your car, either remove the design if there is an option or pick a new color for the car which will remove a locked design (a design that is not your own), then try to download and apply a design again.

I just tried it with the 2011 Ford Transit SuperSportVan that I received with a green design in Forza 6 and it worked.

I wanted to make a screenshot when this happens again, but currently in Forza 6 it doesn't seem to be possible to capture the car and the thumbnail showing the different designs in one still frame. Here is a recording: